# MS ACCESS 2007 Crashing when using Linked tables in SQL

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a query in MS ACCESS SQL which uses linked tables(Linked to MSSQL 2008 using ODBC). THe query crashes when i try to add filters to the query

Eg: Select Col1 , Col2 from LinkedTableA where Col_3_TypeDecimal = (Select unique value from Linked_TableB) works perfectly

But if i try to filter more like

"Select Col1 , Col2 from LinkedTableA where ROUND(Col_3_TypeDecimal,2) = (Select unique value from Linked_TableB)" -- Crashes
The entire database crashes when i try to execute the above 2nd query.

Please help me with any suggestions or examples.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think by rounding column 3 you are preventing SQL Server from using the indexes on LinkedTableA. It is then sending all the data to access to figure out. Have you considered writing this as a passthrough query?

Comment: you may be right, i ended up downloading that entire table to access db and the query was fine(not a good one, but was lucky since it was small)

Answer (score 0):

linked tables suck in MS Access. Move to Access Data Projects, they are superior, and they don't crash.

I started using ADP 12 years ago because I was tired of Jet queries that would corrupt data or give messages like 'too complex to be evaluated'.

Comment: Microsoft dropped ADP support from Access 2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj618413(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: so what he's not using Access 2013

Comment: I added that warning for readers who want their applications to work with Access 2013 and future versions.